# Is there a way to set a stopped GCE instance to preemptible via gcloud compute instance set-scheduling?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gsutil

Is there a way after stopping a google VM from the command line to change said VM to preemptible (without creating it again).

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
#tried but non-working function:

gcloud compute instances set-scheduling vmname --preemptible TRUE
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/851806/hot-to-change-preemptibilty-setting-on-vm-instance-in-google-cloud and https://serverfault.com/questions/919714/enable-preemptible-on-existing-gcp-compute-engine

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. This is equivalent to the AWS Spot instance, and the instances billing function is set at startup and is immutable.

"[Preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/) VMs offer the same machine types and options as regular compute instances and last for up to 24 hours.", so you are going to have to recreate that functionality on a standard node.

What you can do is deploy a new VM using your existing Disks as boot and additional disk and this time selecting preemtible